# Custom Init() translation from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, skspritenode

Sorry for a newbie question but can someone help with translating this to Swift?

```
-(instancetype)init
{
  self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"character.png"];
  {.
    self.name = playerName;
    self.zPosition = 10;
  }
  return self;
}
```

it's for a child of SKSpriteNode

When I try to call `super.init(imageNamed: "character.png")`  I get an error saying `Must call a designated Initialiser of the superclass SKSpriteNode.

If I try to just write it like this:

```
init() {
    super.init()
    self.name = playerName
    self.zPosition = 10
}
```

I get an error in my GameScene when I call:

```
var player : Player = Player(childNodeWithName(playerName))
```

I get an error about converting the type to string.

Comment: What difficulties are you running into when writing it in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## issue 1

a subclass initializer MUST call the superclass's designated Initializer.

for SKSpritenode that's `initWithTexture: color: size:`

#### SO

a SKTexture can be made from an image directly:
`let texture = SKTexture(imageName: "character.png")`

a color:
`let color = UIColor.clearColor()`

then:
`super.init(texture: texture color:color size:texture.size)`

## issue 2:

class player needs an initialiser that takes a SKNode:
`init(node: SKNode) {
    ...
}`

Comment: disclaimer: written inline, might contain typos ;)

Comment: Thanks Daij-Djan that did it for the most part,  however, how would you recommend I go bout this part here: `var player : Player = Player(childNodeWithName(playerName))` from my GameScene. I'm following a book on iOS 7 so want to keep with the syntax as best I can.  playerName is just a string "player"

Comment: player needs a valid constructor